# CSS pseudo classes and JQuery Parallax effect causes flickering

Tags: jquery, css, parallax

I am doing a parallax effect using the [parallax.js plugin](https://github.com/pixelcog/parallax.js/). I have some black triangles created out of CSS that overlay a portion of my header div that I am doing the parallax effect on. I noticed that when I scroll down the page, the CSS triangles flicker. You can see this in my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/doss1/por9dh8t/). The issue is very noticeable in IE and FireFox.

**What causes this and is it possible to fix this issue?**

CSS Code:

```
body { background-color: #333; }
#header { background: transparent no-repeat center bottom; position: relative; height: 100%; background-size: cover; overflow: hidden; }

.big-triangle:after,.big-triangle:before {
content:'';
position:absolute;
bottom:0;
width:50%;
z-index:100;
border-bottom:75px solid black;
-moz-transform:rotate(0.000001deg);
-webkit-transform:rotate(0.000001deg);
-o-transform:rotate(0.000001deg);
-ms-transform:rotate(0.000001deg);
transform:rotate(0.000001deg);}

.big-triangle:before{
right:50%;
border-right:1000px solid transparent;
border-left:1000px solid;}

.big-triangle:after{
left:50%;
border-left:1000px solid transparent;
border-right:1000px solid;}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a pure CSS parallax technique which solved the problem. The link to the [tutorial is here](http://callmenick.com/post/simple-parallax-scrolling-effect).